# Android device connection broken in Sierra

Tags: usb, android, macos

I've recently updated my MBP Retina 2013 to Sierra GM, and today it stopped to connect the Android devices.

I have Android SDK installed and lots of devices available with different OS versions. But when I connect them to my MacBook, they are only charging, ADB does not work and I do not see them connected to USB at all:

```
$ ioreg -p IOUSB
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 17>
  +-o Root Hub Simulation Simulation@1d000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000002c4, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 9>
  | +-o IOUSBHostDevice@1d100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002c6, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 12>
  |   +-o IOUSBHostDevice@1d180000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002e8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 13>
  |     +-o Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad@1d182000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000309, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (162 ms), retain 15>
  |     +-o BRCM20702 Hub@1d181000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000324, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 12>
  |       +-o Bluetooth USB Host Controller@1d181300  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000352, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 17>
  +-o Root Hub Simulation Simulation@1a000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000002cb, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 9>
  | +-o IOUSBHostDevice@1a100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002cd, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 12>
  |   +-o FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)@1a110000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000503, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (114 ms), retain 19>
  +-o Root Hub Simulation Simulation@14000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000012c4, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 8>
```

When I connect my iPhone:

```
$ ioreg -p IOUSB
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 17>
  +-o Root Hub Simulation Simulation@1d000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000002c4, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 9>
  | +-o IOUSBHostDevice@1d100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002c6, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 12>
  |   +-o IOUSBHostDevice@1d180000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002e8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 13>
  |     +-o Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad@1d182000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000309, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (172 ms), retain 15>
  |     +-o BRCM20702 Hub@1d181000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000324, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 12>
  |       +-o Bluetooth USB Host Controller@1d181300  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000352, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 17>
  +-o Root Hub Simulation Simulation@1a000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000002cb, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 9>
  | +-o IOUSBHostDevice@1a100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002cd, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 12>
  |   +-o FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)@1a110000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000503, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (122 ms), retain 19>
  +-o Root Hub Simulation Simulation@14000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000012c4, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 9>
    +-o iPhone@14200000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100001414, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (3 ms), retain 19>
```

I've already tried:

- Windows way (reboot MacBook, reboot devices).
- Use different USB cable.
- Connect to different port (2 available).
- Use different devices (already tried 3 Samsung devices, 1 Asus and 1 HTC).

Everything was fine for a few days after the update, but does not work today.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem resolved by itself. I don't know how and why, but now I can connect any Android device.

Very strange bug.

@Monomeeth, thanks for guide anyway!

Answer (score 3):

One thing I noticed you haven't tried is resetting the PRAM/NVRAM or the SMC.

**Resetting the PRAM/NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). Here’s how to reset your PRAM/NVRAM:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the power button *and then* press the command-option-p-r keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

**Reset the SMC**

Your computer's System Management Controller (SMC) can also be reset. The instructions for resetting your SMC depend on three things:

- Does your device run from a built-in battery? *(In your case, yes)*
- Does your device run from a removable battery?
- Does your device just run off power from the wall?

Now, for the sake of others who may come here looking for answers to the same issue, I will provide the process for all three.

**For MacBook Pros, MacBook Airs, and MacBooks where you can’t remove the battery on your own (i.e. it's a built-in battery), here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time shift-option-control (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the power button
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

**For MacBook Pros, MacBooks etc that you can remove the battery from, here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. **Disconnect** the MagSafe plug (power cable) from the computer
3. Remove the battery
4. Press the power button for 5 seconds and release
5. Put the battery back in
6. Reconnect the MagSafe cord (or power cable)
7. Turn your computer back on with the power button

**For iMacs, Mac Pros, Mac Minis, etc that only run from a power point in the wall**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Unplug it from the power
3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds
4. Plug it back in and turn it on.

Hope this helps. Please report back and let us know.